# My spotlight dont work and preview is dark

Tags: lighting

My spot light is dark, so I checked preview on the light option,
As following image,it’s only dark, but I have not changed position of option.

Only when I set sunlight is lighting right

[image: spot_settings]

Comment: it would be nice if you could change to english before posting a screenshot here because the forum's language is english ;)

Comment: @Chris I've edited the question so that everyone can read it...

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ...wasn't that hard since apart from the characters it's exactly the same :D

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because your *Radius* is far too large (99999.641). For me, the spotlight starts to show in the preview (makes the preview slightly grey) at around 40m and the spot "circle" becomes visible around .5m

[image: Radius]

Comment: That's exactly his problem... since the "amount" of light / wattage is distributed over the complete radius or rathe the resulting area, there are almost no "photons" per square meter to light up the scene. And the sun doesn't use this radius value, that's why it's still working.